# Show rest of text after click on TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

At this moment I have a `TextBlock` like this:

```
<TextBlock MaxLines="4"
            Name="DescriptionText" 
            Grid.Row="1" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            FontWeight="Thin"
            Foreground="White"
            FontSize="18"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
            Margin="0,10,10,0"/>
```

I would have to after click on this `TextBlock` show rest of text in this 2 lines I set in `MaxLines`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle between the max line and unset

Create event

```
<TextBlock    
    MaxLines="2"
    Name="DescriptionText" 
    Grid.Row="1" 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    FontWeight="Thin"
    Foreground="White"
    FontSize="18"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
    Margin="0,10,10,0" 
    Tapped = "DescriptionText_Tapped"/>
```

And alternate between the desired max and default.

```
private void DescriptionText_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    DescriptionText.MaxLines = DescriptionText.MaxLines == 0 ? 2 : 0;
}
```

Now every time you tap the text block it will toggle between the two values.

Comment: Works great. I have a question, it is possible to show only next parts of text in the same textblock?

Comment: @K.Kempski, I do not understand what you mean? can you clarify.

Comment: Firstly i show for example 500 characters of text.
Total characters number of text is 1000. After tapped i would to show 500-1000 characters

Comment: No, the `MaxLine` truncates the display text. when removed it displays all. It would require a lot more complicated to implement what you describe there.

Answer (score 1):

Set `MaxLines` as `0` in Tapped Event

```
private void DescriptionText_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DescriptionText.MaxLines = 0;
}
```